# What is the fastest way to iterate through siblings using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Something like

```
for (var k = 0; k < $('#somediv > p').length; ++k)
    console.log($('#somediv > p:nth-of-type(' + k.toString() + ')');
```

cannot possibly be efficient since `p` elements are iterated through multiple times. What is the most efficient way of doing the above?

Comment: Why does `each()` not work for you? `$('#somediv > p').each(function() { /* your logic */ });`

Comment: Not using jQuery is very likely a lot faster.

Comment: Certainly not efficient since the logic makes no sense to search the DOM again when you already have a collection of DOM elements

Comment: What are you trying to do? If it is doing anything like changing class or any other method that is the same for each element then you wouldn't even need a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- store `$('#somediv > p')` in a variable instead of repeating the selection on every loop turn
- don't use `:nth-of-type( k )` in an iteration. Just select all of them at once, and iterate the collection you get as a result.

In summary: `$('#somediv > p')` does already give you the result you want. Just iterate through it using jQuery's idiomatic [`each` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) - a plain js loop would be faster, but that's neglible.

```
$('#somediv > p').each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

---

Of course, if you look for raw speed, don't use jQuery at all. It might be something like

```
var els = document.getElementById("somediv").children;
for (var i=0, l=els.length; i<l; i++)
    if (els[i].tagName == "P")
        console.log(els[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var i = 0, p = document.getElementById("somediv").querySelectorAll("p");
do {
  console.log(p[i]);
  ++i;
} while(i < p.length )
```

```js
var i = 0, p = document.getElementById("somediv").querySelectorAll("p");
do {
  console.log(p[i]);
  ++i;
} while(i < p.length )
```

```html
<div id="somediv">
  <p>0</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
  </div>
```